# Integration testing of func in OSGI container

Tags: testing, osgi, integration, fuseesb

I'm using FuseESB to run my app, which is essensially OSGI container (Felix), i'd like to figure approach to test my OSGI services in integration mode (including outer dependencies like DB, outer services, etc). First on a thought is ability to run specific bundle into container which involve all app services into running tests defined in this bundle. Can somebody help with that kind of issue? THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differnt ways of testing this. 
Since FuseESB is based on Apache Karaf you might test with the apache karaf-pax-exam tools to test a complete container setup automatically. 
Another way of just testing your OSGi bundles in a OSGi container is to use pax-exam directly. Last but not least if you just want to test your service look-up functionality you might test with pojosr, it's quite nice for testing but has it's limits especially if you depend on container features. 
That said you'll find information at the following pages:

[Pax-Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Pax+Exam)

[Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/)

[sample how Pax-Web uses pax-exam in its iTests](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/itest)

Comment: Nice summary of test options Achim. In this case I would tend to use karaf exam as the test sounds like a lot of infrastructure is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may find http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/how-to-test-osgi-applications/ helpful as an overview of the various OSGi test options. Configuring PAX-Exam to pull in your whole FuseESB container and get all your app services present will involve certain challenges, but once you've got the knack it can be very handy.

Comment: that's where pax-exam-karaf has it's powers, it's a "pre-configured" set to play with karaf easily :)

Answer (score -1):

bndtools as the possibility to do JUnit tests inside the container.